# ESLint import order rule - does not work with .scss files

Tags: eslint

I'm using the following rule:
https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/main/docs/rules/order.md

And i have this in my config:

```
{
  pathGroups: [
  {
    pattern: '*.scss',
    group: 'index',
    patternOptions: { matchBase: true },
    position: 'after'
  }
}
```

Yet when i import something like:

```
import '../../styling/App.scss'
```

It doesn't complain about that `import` at the very top instead of being at the very bottom.
Am i missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered the same problem.
After some research, it seems that `eslint` community does not want to add auto-sorting for [unassigned imports](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/issues/1639#issuecomment-580862011) due to the fact, that they might depend on import order.
That is the reason, why your snippet of `pathGroups` does not work, if it would be an assigned imported, it would work without problems. i.e.:

```js
import styles from '../../styling/App.scss';
```

As a precaution they have added a configurable property ([warnOnUnassignedImports](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/pull/1990)) to warn users when imports might cause undesired outcomes if they are out of order.

The most simple solution, which I found helps is adding an additional plugin just for [css import order](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-css-import-order).

Hope this helps anyone who might have encountered a similar issue.